# Partition numbers in n arrays

Tags: javascript, math

Let's say that we have array of this numbers:

```
var numbers=[10,25,640,9800,51000,54234,53433,543,1000];
```

I want to split those numbers based on their values in n-areas (arrays). Max n is 5.

Examples:

```
Result for 5-area would be: [10,25],[543,640],[1000],[9800],[51000,54234,53433]
Result for 4-area in this case would be: [10,25],[543,640,1000],[9800],[51000,54234,53433]
```

*Edit:

If we have value 900 instead of 640 result for 5 - area would be:

`[10,25],[543],[900,1000],[9800],[51000,54234,53433]`

Because 900 is closer to 1000. In previous example 640 is closer to 543.

--

How should I do that?

Please, help me out.

Comment: You need to define also the function "closer" as something related to the magnitude, if you don't want the partition [10,25,543,640,1000], [9800], [51000], [53433], [54234].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question and description on the 'n-areas', it is unclear exactly what the algorithm entails.

However, for sorting the numbers, you should take a look at the Array sort method.

If the result is negative, the sort function will sort the first value as the lower value and move it down the array. E.G. 10 is the lowest in the collection, so it will be moved to index 0. However, after sorting, after the number 640 in the array above, it will not be 9800, but rather 1000, which will then be followed by 9800. Like this

[10, 25, 543, 640, 1000, 9800, 51000, 53433, 54234]

as opposed to the original array

[10,25,640,9800,51000,54234,53433,543,1000]

I have included a jsbin below to illustrate how Array.sort works.

http://jsbin.com/zaxopucuye/edit?html,js,console

Comment: thanks for your time. Can you look on my updated post and try to understand algorithm? It's more math thing than programming :).

Comment: Hmmm it is still not clear as to exactly how many values we should compare before creating an inner array with the set amount of values. 

but if you are going through the elements and comparing the values, I suggest looping through the elements and comparing the next and previous value (except for in the first iteration e.g. when i=0, where you would only compare the next as there are no previous values).

Likewise, for the last item, you would only compare it with the previous element, as there are no "next elements" after the last item.

Comment: Thanks for idea. We need to compare all values in array.

Comment: Yeah, you probably know the algorithm and relationship between the 5-area and 4-area. 
Just to give you an idea, I ve written a for-loop to hopefully give you some ideas on how to get started on figuring this out 

http://jsbin.com/qaqupefaba/edit?html,js,console